# SQL Server : check if table exists, otherwise create it

Tags: sql-server

I have this code I am converting from MySQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
               WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND TABLE_NAME = 'odds_soccer') 
    CREATE TABLE "odds_soccer" (...)
```

Only problem is... If I try run it twice, it will stump second time with error

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   There is already an object named 'odds_soccer' in the database.

Since I actually found my solution at SO, I am not sure why the code is not working.

I am currently running it as a query from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio having selected my database.

Comment: If i drop schema part - and use this - it appears to work:

IF (NOT( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'odds_soccer') ))

Since this is actually code generated by software with no particular knowledge about the underlying DB (odds_soccer is just an example, could be whatever data, columns etc.) ---- would this not be the most compatible code to generate/use?

Answer (score 11):

For creating table

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                   FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                   WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
                          AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema')
BEGIN
    create..
END
```

For dropping existing table create new table

```
IF Object_id('TEMPDB.schema_name.table', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE table;
```

Comment: Same problem as current code.  (Note: I do not want to drop the table first.)

Comment: @tom then what are you expecting can you elobarate

Comment: I only wan to create a table if it does no already exist. If it already exists I want to keep it and the data in it. (And simply add the data I have)

Comment: @tom then first code is enough to create and insert

Comment: Well, I can not get he schema part working - but if I leave it out it works

Comment: Why completely different queries for create table and drop table? Shouldn't they use the same methodology and just opposite condition?

Comment: @Samuel Neff Either method can be used to test if the table exists. Experiment with `SELECT Object_id('TEMPDB.schema_name.table', 'U')` and `SELECT * FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. The `EXISTS` operator returns true when the `SELECT` statement returns at least one result. Chanukya is clearly a lion, and the fact of the matter is that the nature of the lion is to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 9):

Your `SELECT` query looks for a table within the `'TheSchema'` schema, whereas the table is created in the default schema, usually `dbo`, since no schema name is specified in the `CREATE` statement.

Try using this script instead:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
               WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND TABLE_NAME = 'odds_soccer') 
    CREATE TABLE [TheSchema].odds_soccer (...)
```

Comment: I've really got to start reading all the answers before I start typing... I was a good way into typing exactly this when I stopped and re-read all the other answers...  Discarded the draft since you answered it perfectly.

Comment: It would be possible that his database user has `TheSchema` specified as the default schema. I guess the OP doesn’t give quite enough information to conclude if this is the issue or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Rather surprised as it should work, however it might depend on the SQL-Server version.

Currently I'm using a script like this:

```
DECLARE @SchemaID int = (SELECT schema_id FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'X')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Y' AND schema_id = @SchemaID)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE...
END
GO
```

But that basically is the same.